# Pandas Pipes - keyword argument issue

Tags: pandas, pipe

I write 15 simple functions and want to simply apply these using Pandas Pipe.  any suggestions on how to write functions properly so that they can be piped?  I find any examples on this hard to find.

One function example looks like this:
def invalid_age(df): #Func 6 -remember to do the function "transform_nan" after this function

```
now = pd.to_datetime('now')
df['Age'] = (now.year - df['MemberDOB'].dt.year) - ((now.month - df['MemberDOB'].dt.month) < 0)
df["Age_Invalid"] = (df["Age"] <15) | (df["Age"] > 110)
return df

print('\n\n\ninvalid_age(df):\n')
display(invalid_age(df))
```

All together my pipeline looks like this:

```
df_cleaned = (df.pipe(copy_df).
 pipe(missing_zero_values_table).
 pipe(duplicates).pipe(date_time).pipe(invalid_age).



pipe(char_phone).pipe(char_zip).pipe(phone_clean).pipe(is_not_10).pipe(valid_email).
 pipe(invalid_email).pipe(transform_nan).pipe(zip_code_clean).pipe(name_length).pipe(name_invalid))
```

My question is how to assign the arguments as each function gets applied to the entire df though each will mostly affect one column.  Do I simple do something like: .pipe(invalid_age, "MemberDOB") to make it work on that column?  Then I would change each function to df and replace Member DOB with "column"?  It is not 100% clear to me.

My colab is here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IkYyNdwL2eAuK6YfAHsoW3ncePD5RyON?usp=sharing#scrollTo=OgKShqQZbRsy

Now I am getting an error

### Your selected dataframe has 19 columns and 10000 Rows.
There are 9 columns that have missing values.

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df_cleaned = (df.pipe(copy_df).
2 pipe(missing_zero_values_table).pipe(duplicates)).pipe(date_time).pipe(invalid_age).pipe(char_phone).pipe(char_zip).pipe(phone_clean).pipe(is_not_10).pipe(valid_email).pipe(invalid_email).pipe(transform_nan)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in pipe(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
5046         ...  )  # doctest: +SKIP
5047     """
-> 5048         return com.pipe(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
5049
5050     _shared_docs["aggregate"] = dedent(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in pipe(obj, func, *args, **kwargs)
469         return func(*args, **kwargs)
470     else:
--> **471         **return func(obj, *args, **kwargs)****
472
473

**TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

Comment: This question is a little confusing to me, can you restate with more simple code and example?

Comment: yes of course.  So I write 15 functions, for example and want to apply PANDAS PIPE to the.  Here is one example:def valid_email(df): #we write a function applying validate_email which verifies email format and its SMTP server
    
    df['is_valid_email'] = df['MemberEmail'].apply(lambda x:validate_email(x))

    return df
df = valid_email(df)
df.head(5) Can I simple do this: df_cleaned = (df.pipe(copy_df).pipe(phone_clean).pipe(is_not_10).pipe(valid_email)) etc and avoid adding a column name as the data columns will remain the same.?

Comment: My error (shortended)

df_cleaned = (df.pipe(copy_df).
 pipe(missing_zero_values_table).
 pipe(duplicates).pipe(date_time).pipe(invalid_age).
 pipe(char_phone).pipe(char_zip).pipe(phone_clean).pipe(is_not_10).pipe(valid_email).
 pipe(invalid_email).pipe(transform_nan).pipe(zip_code_clean).pipe(name_length).pipe(name_invalid))
Your selected dataframe has 14 columns and 5000 Rows.
There are 6 columns that have missing values.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable